# Why are query results shortened in pgAdmin 1.18.1?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I've recently installed pgAdmin 1.18.1 and noticed a strange thing:

Long json query results are shortened to 256 symbols and then ' (...)' is added.

Could someone help me disable this shortening?

Comment: SuperUser seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a setting for that in the options: `Max characters per column` - useful when dealing with big columns. Obviously your setting is 256 characters.

[image: pgAdmin / Query editor - options dialog]

Set it higher or set it to `-1` to disable the feature.
Consult [the fine manual here](http://pgadmin.org/docs/1.18/options-query_tool.html) for more details.

Comment: For people who are searching where Options is it is there under file menu http://i.stack.imgur.com/0bfxy.png