# List all columns and rows of PostgreSQL table with a view limit

Tags: postgresql

I am currently using `select * from items;` to show my table during development however I am finding it a bit messy now as some the strings I am adding to the table are 1,000+ chars long.

Is there a modification to the command `select * from items;` that will simply refuse to show any character past 10 or 15 of all the fields in the database?

I am viewing the table via terminal for development reasons.

Comment: Do you just want the column names or do you really want the first 'x' characters from each column?

Comment: I'm trying to get a cleaner output of my table where a lot of my fields are very long. The actual names of the columns are not an issue.

I guess what I am trying to get is a dump of a table that is compact and readable.

Comment: Create a view where long columns are replaced by `substr(long_column,N)`

Comment: pgAdmin has a feature doing exactly that: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52399/why-are-query-results-shortened-in-pgadmin-1-18-1/52926#52926