# Query plan (JSON format) in pgAdmin not showing completely

Tags: postgresql, json, pgadmin

I would like to use the tool [Postgres Explain Viewer (PEV)](http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/new). For it I need to paste the execution plan in json format. If I try to get the execution plan in pgAdmin with this query:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)
SELECT DISTINCT key
FROM test.table
```

I don't get the whole json:

query plan

[image]

Can I get the whole json? Could I export it from the SQL editor?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `DISTINCT` is **not**  a function. `distinct (key)` is exactly the same thing as `distinct key`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Worse, even: `distinct (key)` only *happens*
 to "work" because ROW values with a single expression are replaced with the nested expression. Not the case for more than one expression like `distinct (key, values)` ...

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52926/3684 If the OP would be so kind as to disclose the version of pgAdmin in use ...

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed to know. I'm new here... Should I delete my question because it's duplicated?

Comment: @MLD: It's been "closed" as duplicate and good to stay as is. Please remember to disclose relevant software versions for your next question.